# Openmpi setting btl flags --mca btl tcp vs --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1

Tags: mpi, openmp, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, openmpi

I am looking the documentation of how to set `btl` flags to use network specific protocol and specific connection.

I am seeing the [btl selection](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp#tcp-selection) [general documentation](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect20) documentation, but a bit confused.

What I understand (please correct me if I am wrong) If I want to use `tcp` protocol I need to specify `--mca btl tcp`. And if I want to use ethernet1 as connection device then I need to specify `--mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1`. 
So if I want to use both of these setting I will set both ?
 `--mca btl tcp` `--mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1` or just setting `--mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1` will be okay?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do

```
mpirun --mca pml ob1 --mca btl tcp,self --mca btl_tcp_if_include eth1 ...
```

A few comments :

- to be on the safe side, you should force the use of `pml/ob1` component (otherwise you might end up using richer interfaces such as UCX of OFI)
- `pml/ob1` uses the *best* `btl` components for point to point communication
- you must always include the `btl/self` component
- in your case, you want to force the use of `btl/tcp`
- and you need to tell `btl/tcp` to use the `eth1` interface. setting this parameter does not force the use of the `btl/tcp` component, that is why you have to manually request it